# create a many to many relationship with flask_sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to create a relationship between users and Events. I want users to be able to register for events.

I already have a user and event model on a one to many relationships

### user model

```
class User(db.Model,UserMixin):

  __tablename__ = 'users'

  id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key = True)
  .........
  events = db.relationship('Event',backref='organiser', lazy=True)
```

##events model

```
class Event(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'events'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key = True)
    ........
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=False)
```

I need help to create a table for users registrations. The table should contain additional fields, not just the event and user ids

I want to be able to do queries like

```
user.event_registrations
event.event_registrations
event.event_registrations.users
user.events
```

This is my attempt to create the table following the documentation.

```
class EventRegistration(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'event_registrations'
    user_id = Column(ForeignKey('users.id'), primary_key=True)
    event_id = Column(ForeignKey('events.id'), primary_key=True)
    extra_data1 = Column(String(50))
    extra_data2 = Column(String(50))
    event = db.relationship("Event", back_populates="users")
    user = db.relationship("Member", back_populates="events")

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    ....
    events = db.relationship("EventRegistration", back_populates="user")

class Event(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'events'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    ....
    users = db.relationship("EventRegistration", back_populates="event")
```

Help to set up the database properly
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The right way to create a many-to-many relationship is to create an association table

```
Events=db.Table('Events',
db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('user.id'),primary_key=True),
db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('event.id'),primary_key=True)
)

        class User(db.Model,UserMixin):
        
          __tablename__ = 'users'
        
          id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key = True)
          .........
          events = db.relationship('Event',secondary=Events,backref='organiser', lazy=True)
    
    class Event(db.Model):
    
        __tablename__ = 'events'
    
        id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key = True)
        ........
```

if you want more info about many-to-many I advise you to read this [Article](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-viii-followers)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't created a true [many-to-many](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/models/#many-to-many-relationships) relationship you have created a few [one-to-many](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/models/#one-to-many-relationships) relationships.

To make that clear, in a many-to-many relationship, `User.events` would give you a list of `Events`. In your case, you get a list of `EventRegistrations`.

That being said you probably don't need to go the many-to-many route, you just need to fix your one-to-many relationships. The [docs](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/models/#one-to-many-relationships) can help with that but it looks like you are mixing `ForeignKeys` and `primary_keys`. Don't do that, and follow the example in the docs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. All I want to do is to create a functionality where users can register for an event by clicking on a registration button/action. when they click on the button/action, an entry is added to the registration table including the user's id and the event id with some extra fields. Maybe many to many relationships are not needed here.